# Serialize Java Enum with properties as json object

Tags: java, gson, jax-rs, moshi

In Java, it's trivial to add meta properties to an enum class:

```java
public enum ItemType {

    NORMAL("Normal Item", 10, false),
    SPECIAL("Special Item", 20, false),
    RARE("Rare Item", 30, true);

    private final String description;
    private final int points;
    private final boolean magical;

    private ItemType(String description, int points, boolean magical) {
        this.description = description;
        this.points = points;
        this.magical = magical;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public boolean isMagical() {
        return magical;
    }
}
```

I would like to serialize these as such, but only on-demand at certain rest endpoints (ie, normal serialization should still apply where the enum name is converted to a string: `NORMAL`, `SPECIAL`, or `RARE`):

```json
{
   "_enum": "NORMAL",
   "description": "Normal Item",
   "points": 10,
   "magical": false
}
```

Is there any way to annotate my enum so that gson or moshi can generate a json object like that?  Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a general solution that covers all cases, resp. all libraries, but this would be a solution for gson

```
class ItemTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ItemType> {

    private final String ENUM_ID = "_enum";

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, ItemType itemType) throws IOException {
        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name(ENUM_ID).value(itemType.name());
        writer.name("description").value(itemType.getDescription());
        writer.name("points").value(itemType.getPoints());
        writer.name("magical").value(itemType.isMagical());
        writer.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemType read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        String itemType = null;
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals(ENUM_ID)) {
                itemType = reader.nextString();
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        if (itemType != null) {
            return ItemType.valueOf(itemType);
        } else {
            throw new JsonParseException("Missing '" + ENUM_ID + "' value");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom `JsonSerializer` resp. `JsonDeserializer`. To use this, you'll need to register this as a custom type adapter when building the gson-object.
There is probably a similar solution for other libraries/frameworks